# Sharing GeoPackage for collaborative work (web, ftp, cloud...)

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I would like to share a GeoPackage as part of a GIS project (QGIS) with one of my customer. Only the customer will edit the GPKG.

I could use a cloud service like Google, Dropbox or pCloud. But that assumes that the other one has got a cloud account too. Could I also use an HTTP or FTP-Server? How?

I prefer to use GeoPackage instead of PostGIS because it's easier to share and backup.

Comment: I have not tried it but cant you use geoserver and WFS standard? And then the customer can edit the gpkg using for example QGIS

Comment: Hey, what about sharing .gpkg files as email attachments?  If they're not over ~ 20 MB you're good to go!

Comment: You can certainly have WFS and GeoPackage as one output using MapServer

Comment: do you want to send it to the customer or publish it where only the customer can edit?